# How to group multiple values to only two groups?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have 2 tables.

`Type` table

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | General |
| 2. | Mostly Used |
| 3. | Low |

`Component` table

| id | Name | typeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Component 1 | 1 |
| 2. | Component 2 | 1 |
| 4. | Component 4 | 2 |
| 6. | Component 6 | 2 |
| 7. | Component 5 | 3 |

There can be numerous types but I want to get only 'General' and 'Others' as types along with the component as follows:

```
[{
"General": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "General",
    "component": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "component 1",
        "componentTypeId": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "component 2",
        "componentTypeId": 1
    }]
}],
"Others": [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Mostly Used",
        "component": [{
            "id": 4,
            "name": "component 4",
            "componentTypeId": 2
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "component 6",
            "componentTypeId": 2
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Low",
        "component": [{
            "id": 7,
            "name": "component 5",
            "componentTypeId": 3
        }]
    }
]
```

}]

```
    WITH CTE_TYPES AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN t. "name" <> 'General' THEN
            'Others'
        ELSE
            'General'
        END AS TYPE,
        t.id,
        t.name
    FROM
        type AS t
    GROUP BY
        TYPE,
        t.id
),
CTE_COMPONENT AS (
    SELECT
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.typeid
    FROM
        component c
)
SELECT
    JSON_AGG(jsonb_build_object ('id', CT.id, 'name', CT.name, 'type', CT.type, 'component', CC))
FROM
    CTE_COMPONENTTYPES CT
    INNER JOIN CTE_COMPONENT CC ON CT.id = CC.tradingplancomponenttypeid
GROUP BY
    CT.type
```

I get 2 types from the query as I expected but the components are not grouped together

Can you also point to resources to learn advanced SQL queries?

Comment: What about the JSON format in the displayed result? What have you tried? Your version of Postgres?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter I have updated my query with my SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here after is a solution to get your expected result as specified in your question :

**First part**

The first part of the query aggregates all the components with the same `TypeId` into a jsonb array. It also calculates the new `type` column with the value '*Others*' for all the type names different from `General` or with the value '*General*'  :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.name <> 'General' THEN 'Others' ELSE 'General' END AS type
     , t.id, t.name
     , jsonb_build_object('id', t.id, 'name', t.name, 'component', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', c.id, 'name', c.name, 'componentTypeId', c.typeid))) AS list
  FROM component AS c
 INNER JOIN type AS t
    ON t.id = c.typeid
 GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

[jsonb_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) builds a jsonb object from a set of key/value arguments

[jsonb_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) aggregates jsonb objects into a single jsonb array.

**Second part**

The second part of the query is much more complex because of the structure of your expected result where you want to nest the types which are different from `General` with their components inside each other according to the `TypeId` order, ie `Low` type with `TypeId = 3` is nested inside `Mostly Used` type with `TypeId = 2` :

```
{ "id": "2",
,  "name": "Mostly Used"
, "component": [ { "id": 4
                 , "name": "component 4"
                 , "componentTypeId": 2
                 }
               , { ... }
               , { "id": "3"
                 , "name": "Low"  --> 'Low' type is nested inside 'Mostly Used' type
                 , "component": [ { "id": 7
                                  , "name": "component 5"
                                  , "componentTypeId": 3
                                  }
                                , { ... }
                                ]
                 }
               ]
}
```

To do such a nested structure with a random number of `TypeId`, you could create a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE), but I prefer here to create a user-defined [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) which will make the query much more simple and readable, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html). The aggregate function `jsonb_set_inv_agg` is based on the user-defined function `jsonb_set_inv` which inserts the jsonb object `x` inside the existing jsonb object `z` according to the path `p`. This function is based on the [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) standard function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_set_inv(x jsonb, p text[], z jsonb, b boolean)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
  SELECT jsonb_set(z, p, COALESCE(z#>p || x, z#>p), b) ;
$$ ;

CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_set_inv_agg(p text[], z jsonb, b boolean)
( sfunc = jsonb_set_inv
, stype = jsonb
) ;
```

Based on the newly created aggregate function `jsonb_set_inv_agg` and the `jsonb_agg` and `jsonb_build_object` standard functions already seen above, the final query is :

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('General', x.list)) FILTER (WHERE x.type = 'General')
    || jsonb_build_object('Others', jsonb_set_inv_agg('{component}', x.list, true ORDER BY x.id DESC) FILTER (WHERE x.type = 'Others'))
  FROM 
     ( SELECT CASE WHEN t.name <> 'General' THEN 'Others' ELSE 'General' END AS type
            , t.id, t.name
            , jsonb_build_object('id', t.id, 'name', t.name, 'component', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', c.id, 'name', c.name, 'componentTypeId', c.typeid))) AS list
         FROM component AS c
        INNER JOIN type AS t
           ON t.id = c.typeid
        GROUP BY t.id, t.name
     ) AS x
```

see the full test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5f3f7e04c02bf79dcf90ca58e8641f93).

Comment: sorry there was mistake in json, I wanted General and Others type with components. I have edited the JSON. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Your jsonb expected result is still wrong with something missing before the "Others" key. You can easily resuse the first part of my solution and simplify the second part to get your expected result by using `jsonb_agg`  instead of  `jsonb_set_inv_agg`